# Rails 3 Password Protect Single View

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, password-protection

I have gone through and looked at a bunch of screen casts (http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1) and tutorials (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-and-viewing-users-two?version=2.3#sec:secure_passwords) but I can't seem to find or apply what I am learning to create a single view password protected.

As of now I am generating a random password and showing it to the user to go back and view a file they have uploaded (generated using SecureRandom.hex). However, I know that using http_basic doesn't seem to work when I restrict it only to the show view and method in my controller : `http_basic_authenticate_with :password => :passcode, :only => :show`

I know that line of code does not work because :passcode does not reference the individual files password that was created.

Also, I know that http_basic_authenticate_with is not the way it should be done for secure passwords, so how would you go about this using has_secure_password etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to encapsulate the `http_basic_authenticate_with :password => :passcode` in a method in your controller, and call the `before_filter` to call that method.
Something like that:

```
before_filter :restrict, :only => :show

def show
end

def restrict
  http_basic_authenticate_with :password => :passcode
end
```

Comment: The only issue that I get when using the solution is that I am getting the error "undefined method `http_basic_authenticate_with'." Does http_basic_authenticate_with have to be at the top of the controller?

Comment: I do not know if this work, but try to define the method with a self. like: `def self.restrict`.

Comment: I ended up getting this to work:

authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |user, password|
      password == @file.passcode && user == ""
end